# Proving $E_{DFA}$ is decidable by running $A_{DFA}$ several times

Tags: turing-machines, computability, automata

I am trying to prove that language $E_{DFA}$ is decidable using multiple executions of $A_{DFA}$ (not using the proof in Sipser's book "Introduction to the Theory of Computation").

Can I just use the given $M$ as a decider?

> $M =$ "On input $\langle B,w \rangle$, where $B$ is a DFA and $w$ is
>   an empty string ($L(w)=\emptyset$):
>
> 1. Mark the start of the DFA as $q_0$.
> 2. Simulate B on input w a finite number of times:
>
>    1. First check if the encoding is correct, if $L(w)=\emptyset$, if not - reject.
>    2. Recursively: mark states that can be obtained within a finite $δ$
>         operations from any marked states.
> 3. If no accept state marked - accept. else, reject."

Is this correct?

Definitions:
$$\begin{align*}
A_{DFA} &= \left\{ \langle B,w \rangle \mid \text{$B$ is a DFA that accepts input string $w$} \right\} \\
E_{DFA} &= \left\{ \langle A \rangle \mid \text{$A$ is a DFA and $L\left(A\right) = \varnothing$} \right\}
\end{align*}$$

Emphasis: I am trying to prove $E_{DFA}$ by running the proof of $A_{DFA}$ several times (finite), so I thought the correct thing would be to use the input $w$ as empty set.

Comment: Note you can use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>`, respectively, and which are *much* better to read.

Comment: If the DFA has $n$ states and accepts some word, then it accepts some word of length less than $n$.

Comment: would appreciate what is the correct way to do so. i am really unsure above what i've written and it is intriguing me a lot

Comment: I'm not sure what the notation $L(w) = \emptyset$ means. The operator $L$ maps a *DFA* to a *language*. The input is *not* a word. In the text, you mention that you want to use the empty set for the input $w$, but the empty set is not a word.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reduce $E_{DFA}$ to $A_{DFA}$, you should use the following theorem:

> If a DFA with $n$ states accepts some word, then it accepts some word of length less than $n$.

But a much more efficient algorithm would just run DFS from the initial state, and check whether some accepting state is reachable from it.